# Codeigniter - setting dbprefix triggers [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent]

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7, phpactiverecord

I am appending custom selects and table aliases into the query.
Used {PRE} to append prefix to table names in the custom query but it was also adding the prefix to alias in select. if I add

```
{PRE}countries AS c  // output mydb_countries AS c
```

So, when I pass an array to select() method :

`` $select = ['`c`.`Name` AS TITLE']; ``
`$this->db->select($select);`

`//output select 'mydb_c.Name' AS TITLE from mydb_countries AS c`

`//expected select 'c.Name' AS TITLE from mydb_countries AS c`

So, I tried to get rid of  {PER} and change the dbprefix :

`$bkp_prefix = $this->db->dbprefix;`

`$this->db->set_dbprefix(''); // Setting prefix to empty`

`$this->db->select($select); // manually add prefix to table names`

`$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();`

`$this->db->set_dbprefix($bkp_prefix); // Revert prefix to original state`

Results returned are accurate by I get the warning :

`Severity: Warning`
`Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(output`
`started at {file path})`
`Filename: core/Common.php`
`Line Number: 573`
`Backtrace:`

Which create problem while writing the results to CSV.
Although, When I comment :
`//$this->db->set_dbprefix('');`

Warning disappears.

P.S. There is no echo,printr,var_dump any where near my code and the warning i get is before I send my results to generateCSV() method which is in separate module.

Comment: make sure you don't have any space in `index.php` file at first line.

Comment: @pradeep did you read the question correctly.
commenting the $this->db->set_dbprefix(''); removes the warning.
And also at the end i mentioned echo, printr and var_dump are no where near my code. 
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @jagad89 
no space in index.php . It was caused when I set dbprefix to "" (empty string).
Resolved by using __call() 
made my methods private and inside __call before calling my methods I set the prefix to "" and call methods through call_user_func_array() dynamically and after that restore the dbprefix to original state and return the response.
Think of it like premethod/postmethod functinality.

Comment: @jagad89 I rechecked and there is no space in `index.php` file at line.

Comment: are you using `like` or `or_like` query?

Comment: Usually the `Cannot modify header information` error is preceded by some other error. Is none shown or logged?